# Create Git branch feature/x/y?

Tags: git, internationalization, branch

I currently have a Git branch `feature/i18n` which I am using to create different localizations of my app. I want to create a sub-branch for each language so I can integrate them separately. Is it possible to create sub-directories, e.g. `feature/i18n/French` or `feature/i18n/Spanish`, so they are more easily organized? I am getting the following error message from Git: `error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/feature/i18n/spanish: Not a directory`.

Comment: I thought branch names were just that, names.

Comment: Yes, you can. I have no idea why you are getting that error.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The heads of the branches are organized in folders inside `.git/refs/heads`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oh, I see. I use names like this all the time; I guess I just never noticed an issue. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just a comment - I don't quite understand why would you want to create branches for every language instead of just committing them to master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create those branches. The problem preventing you from sub-dividing your i18n namespace, so to speak, is that you already have the `feature/i18n` branch.

Every branch is created as a file under .git/refs/heads, so when you created your branch, Git created the file `.git/refs/heads/feature/i18n`.

Now you're trying to created `.git/refs/heads/feature/i18n/spanish`, for which git tries to create an `i18n` folder -- which it can't, because there is a file of the same name.

To create those "sub-branches", you'll have to delete or rename your `feature/i18n` branch.

Answer (score 2):

you have created a branch feature/i18n

That means you have created a file by name 
feature/i18n.

Now 
to create a file feature/i18n/spanish, i18 must be a Directory.

To fix this delete  feature/i18n branch and create  feature/i18n/spanish